# Trocar classe e id de item ao receber evento click com javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte linha:

```
<li id="fecharMenu">
    <i class="mdi mdi-window-close mdi-24px" id="iconFecharMenu"></i>
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

Quando o usuário clicar na `<li id="fecharMenu">`, o menu fecha e eu gostaria que trocasse o icone e consequentemente, o id da `<li>` do `<i>`, ficando assim:

```
<li id="abrirMenu">
    <i class="mdi mdi-menu mdi-24px" id="iconAbrirMenu"></i>
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

JavaScript que eu tenho atualmente, ele "fecha" o menu apenas, gostaria de trocar o icone e o id da li e do icon também, pra ai poder criar um evento ao clicar no botão de abrir o menu:

```
document.getElementById("fecharMenu").addEventListener("click", fecharMenu);
function fecharMenu() {
    document.getElementById("barraLateral").style.width = "60px";
}
```

Como eu poderia fazer somente com JavaScript, sem usar Jquery?

Comment: aonde está o ícone?

Comment: É o `<i class="mdi mdi-menu mdi-24px" id="iconAbrirMenu"></i>`. É icone do Material Design Icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode trocar os atributos da seguinte forma:

```
document.querySelector("#fecharMenu").addEventListener("click", function(){
   this.id = "abrirMenu"; // troca o id da <li>
   var i = this.children[0]; // seleciona o <i>
   i.id = "iconAbrirMenu"; // troca o id do <i>
   i.className = i.className.replace("mdi-window-close","mdi-menu"); // substitui a classe do <i>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método *setAttribute* para alterar o Id, da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("fecharMenu").setAttribute("id", "abrirMenu");
```

Nesse caso, estou supondo que você tem uma regra css para cada Id de menu:

```
#fecharMenu {
    background-image : (...)
}
#abrirMenu{
    background-image : (...)
}
```

Desta forma, ao modificar o id, você mudará o ícone automaticamente.

Mas, acredito que manipular o Id dessa forma *não seja a melhor prática*. Acredito que manipulando classes seja mais adequado, da seguinte forma:

HTML:

```
<li id="menu" class="aberto">
    <i class="mdi mdi-window-close mdi-24px" id="iconFecharMenu"></i>
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", aoClicarMenu);
function aoClicarMenu(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('aberto'){
        event.target.classList.remove('aberto');
        event.target.classList.add('fechado');
    } else {
        event.target.classList.remove('fechado');
        event.target.classList.add('aberto');
    }
    document.getElementById("barraLateral").style.width = "60px";
}
```

O código acima verifica se o elemento DOM que disparou o evento, no caso, o **li**, contém a classe 'aberto', se sim, ela é removida, e a classe 'fechado' é adicionada, e vice-versa. Assim você vai conseguir alternar o comportamento do elemento a cada clique que ele recebe.
Para isso, você teria que ter um CSS para definir o ícone do menu aberto, ou fechado:

```
.aberto {
    background-image : (...)
}
.fechado {
    background-image : (...)
}
```